# Qtranslate plus support for Wordpress SEO by Yoast

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

Im using Qtranlate plus (https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-xp/) and i also use Wordpress seo by Yoast but the meta title and description fields cant be translated. Anyone have a fix for that or knows a plugin that fixes the issue?

Answer (score 3):

This Problem exists since qTranslate wasn't plus.
There is a fix, from Yoast:
http://kb.yoast.com/article/52-wordpress-seo-qtranslate

---

```
function qtranslate_filter( $text ) {
  return __( $text );
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'qtranslate_filter', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'qtranslate_filter', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'wpseo_metakey', 'qtranslate_filter', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_title', 'qtranslate_filter', 10, 1 );
```

This wasn't enough for me... i traced the $text and saw that the language syntax was broken.
It wasn't

```
<!--:de-->, it was <!-:de->.
```

So i added a replacement for that directly in the qtranslate_filter($..).

```
function qtranslate_filter( $text ) {
    $fixedOpenTag = str_replace("<!-:", "<!--:", $text);
    $fixedCloseTag = str_replace("->", "-->", $fixedOpenTag);
    return __($fixedCloseTag);
}
```

This works for frontend output. I looked in the sourcecode of yoast but haven't fixed it by now...

Comment: Tested to update functions.php with the code but my title field just throws away <!--de--> etc efter saving the page. Then its just three titles without the <!--en--> thing in it @Julian-Kimmig

Comment: Are you editing your titles in "real" pagetitle input for each language or in yoast meta section title input? Which WP and plugin versions are usedg? I'm using WP 4.0, qTranslate Plus Version 2.7.2, Yoast Version 1.6.3. And in Yoast Options > "Titles & Metas", "Force rewrite titles" is "not" enabled. @user2986959

Comment: @user4066959 I have installed Yoast SEO fix for qTranslate that allows me to write [:en]Some title in the SEO title field but it doesnt work in description field. Mine is MQTranslate Version 2.7.1.1. Not same plugin? The script above wasn´t working for me. Still need to translate meta desc.

Comment: You just saved my day! Cheers dude!

Answer (score 0):

I modify the filters and consume the string from the database directly

```
function qtranslate_filter_yoast_title($text)
{
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $text = get_metadata('post', $post_id, "_yoast_wpseo_title", true);
    return __($text);
}
function qtranslate_filter_yoast_desc($text)
{

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $text = get_metadata('post', $post_id, "_yoast_wpseo_metadesc", true);
    return __($text);
}

add_filter('wpseo_title', 'qtranslate_filter_yoast_title', 10, 1);
add_filter('wpseo_metadesc', 'qtranslate_filter_yoast_desc', 10, 1);
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_desc', 'qtranslate_yoast_filter_desc', 10, 1);
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_title', 'qtranslate_filter_yoast_title', 10, 1);
```